# How can i add date based on my data at sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

so i have tables with 2 fields

| date | date_add |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 5 |
| 2022-08-01 | 3 |

and i want this output for my query

| date | date_add | due_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 5 | 2022-08-06 |
| 2022-08-01 | 3 | 2022-08-04 |

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATE_ADD()` function.

```
SELECT date, date_add, DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL date_add DAY) AS due_date
FROM yourTable
```

You could also define a virtual column to do this automatically.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
    ADD COLUMN due_date GENERATED ALWAYS AS DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL date_add DAY) VIRTUAL;
```